# What is the scaling algorithm used by ID3DXFont?

Tags: directx, direct3d, direct3d9

I'm trying to complement ID3DXFont functionality, rendering the text to the texture and then ID3DXSprite.Draw()-ing it as needed.

Old (direct) way:

```
ID3DXSprite *sprite;
ID3DXFont *font;
sprite->SetTransform(mw);
font->DrawText(sprite, ...);
```

New (optimized) way:

```
RenderTextToATexture(texture, ...);
sprite->SetTransform(mw);
sprite->Draw(texture, ...);
```

Text comes out nice and readable no matter the scaling when rendering directly, but gets ugly when rendered to a texture and then scaled as a texture.

See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S7wa.png): First line is rendered by texture scaling, second line is ID3DXFont scaling.

Just to be sure there's no double-scaling I'm saving the (supposedly unscaled) texture to a file. It is [indeed unscaled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVfHS.png) (just pure $000 and $FFF pixels in BMP, even, so no smoothing is at work).

Am I missing something? I've always thought ID3DXFont does the same thing, renders the glyphs into a texture and then blits those into view with Sprite.Draw(). Why does it scale text so much better then?

Comment: Looks like you draw your texture at wrong (non-integer) coordinates and this results in distortion. Try rounding coordinates before drawing.

Comment: @real4x: nope, drawing to integer coordinates (before scaling of course)

Answer (score 0):

ID3DXFont works by rendering the text data directly from the font's glyph data, AFAIK.  What you see is inevitable if you try and downsample any texture.

Comment: D3DXFont cannot render the text "directly": not in Direct3D. It has to render it onto a texture, then put that texture on a quad. Same thing that I do. And indeed it suffers from scaling, just my text suffers more badly (check samples).

Comment: @himself":  Why can't it render them directly just out of interest? I have a font system that builds triangles directly from the glyph data using FreeType so I dont' see why D3DXFont doesn't do that.  In fairness though i do know that D3DXFont can cache text into textures to save rendering time later!

Comment: You mean a 3d font? I give up, it's possible... but complicated and it would be a pain to support every feature of GDI DrawText as D3DXFont does. You lose things like antialiasing, cleartype etc, all of this happens at pixel level as far as I know. Anyway, with the help of DirectX debugger I've discovered that there's a texture being created with all the required glyphs when I draw a text line with D3DXFont; I don't know how they make it scale so good though. It's mipmapped, maybe not with default scaling... Also it's rendered as $FF000000 on $00000000 (alpha channel only).